# ASP.NET MVC Access Application Property from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

my global.asax looks like this

```
Imports Castle.Windsor
Imports Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters

Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
    Implements IContainerAccessor

    Private Shared IoC As IWindsorContainer

    Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        ' MapRoute takes the following parameters, in order:
        ' (1) Route name
        ' (2) URL with parameters
        ' (3) Parameter defaults
        routes.MapRoute( _
            "Default", _
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
        )

    End Sub

    Sub Application_Start()
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        IoC = New WindsorContainer(New XmlInterpreter)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Container() As Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer Implements Castle.Windsor.IContainerAccessor.Container
        Get
            Return IoC
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

how do i access the Container property from within any Model Class?
is there a class i can inherit from that gives me the "Application" property as in the view so i could to this

IoC = Application.Item("Container")...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't want your model objects knowing about your IoC container.

But, for the sake of answering your question, you can access it like this:

(C#)

```
var container = ((IContainerAccessor)MvcApplication).Container;
```

Comment: I want to agree 1000% that you don't want your model objects knowing about your IOC container.  Everything they need from it should get passed to them when they get built.